# How to prevent Contact Form fake e-mailing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, contact-form, spam-prevention, email-spam

I have a contact form in my portfolio website, here -https://twitter.com/Kartikth40/status/1663477835691081733?t=HRG72p4T7ue1JyZ1y3DsiA&s=19

[image]

But recently I am getting some useless and abusive mails under the fake emails.

So is there any way of preventing this fake e-mailing ?

I know I can verify user's emails or even make them login but that will hinder their experience.

Comment: You can add a captcha to prevent bots from filling and submiting that form. And there are some services that can check email addresses for validity to a certain extend (for instance recognizing known domains for one-time email services). But there is no way to definively determine whether `foobar@gmail.com` is a valid address or not  other than verifying that address by sending an email with a link/code

Comment: @derpirscher thanks for the response and I am also thinking so for verifying emails by spending links but I think that will be too much to ask for someone visiting my portfolio